# How to add a new row in DataTable below the existing rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a new row into my `DataTable` and then binding it to the `GridView`(`Inquiries`) each time I click the button. The row is added when I Click the button for the first time. but when I try to add another row by clicking on it again it replaces the existing row.

```
protected void addInquiry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
             Quantity = QuantityTxt.Text;
             string Details = Request.Form[Products.UniqueID];
             SelectedProduct = Details.Split('!');
             ProductNo = SelectedProduct[0];
             ProductDescription = SelectedProduct[1];
             ProductSapPack = SelectedProduct[2];
             ProductID = SelectedProduct[3];
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();                       
             dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { 
                                 new DataColumn("ProductID",typeof(int)),
                                 new DataColumn("ProductNo", typeof(string)),
                                 new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)),
                                 new DataColumn("SapPack",typeof(string)),
                                 new DataColumn("Quantity",typeof(string)),
                                 });

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr[0] = ProductID;
            dr[1] = ProductNo;
            dr[2] = ProductDescription;
            dr[3] = ProductSapPack;
            dr[4] = Quantity;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            Inquiries.DataSource = dt;
            Inquiries.DataBind();
      }

      finally
      {
            QuantityTxt.Text = String.Empty;
            Description.Text = String.Empty;
            SapPack.Text = String.Empty;
            Products.Text = String.Empty;
      }
}
```

Comment: Every time you click the button, you are creating a new `DataTable`. So actually it is not updating the old row rather it is creating new everytime.

Comment: So i should create the DataTable Instance Outside the click Event ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I create My DataTable Instance outside the click event but it still replaces my original Row!

Comment: Ideally you should but that won't work because the page is instantiated after every postback which means your DataTable will be created again. If you really want to do it like this, then probably you can store the DataTable in ViewState variable, but IMHO its not the best way to do it.

Comment: I am Using Ajax to update my datatable and Gridview!

Comment: By your button click definition `addInquiry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` doesn't look like you are using Ajax.

Comment: Actually This button is a part of my UpdatePanel which is retrieving data from database. After getting data from database i am setting it to a new data Table and then I am binding it to my gridview Control.

Comment: I didn't post those details because that part is working perfectly! I am having troubles in just adding a new row into my Datatable and then Binding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer that Worked For me was this

```
protected void addInquiry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataTable dt=(DataTable)Session["Inquiry"];
  try
  {
         Quantity = QuantityTxt.Text;
         string Details = Request.Form[Products.UniqueID];
         SelectedProduct = Details.Split('!');
         ProductNo = SelectedProduct[0];
         ProductDescription = SelectedProduct[1];
         ProductSapPack = SelectedProduct[2];
         ProductID = SelectedProduct[3];
         if(dt==null)
         {
             dt= new DataTable(); 
             dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { 
                             new DataColumn("ProductID",typeof(int)),
                             new DataColumn("ProductNo", typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("SapPack",typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("Quantity",typeof(string)),
                             });

         }             


        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr[0] = ProductID;
        dr[1] = ProductNo;
        dr[2] = ProductDescription;
        dr[3] = ProductSapPack;
        dr[4] = Quantity;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Inquiries.DataSource = dt;
        Inquiries.DataBind();
        Session.Add("Inquiry",dt);
  }
  finally
  {
        QuantityTxt.Text = String.Empty;
        Description.Text = String.Empty;
        SapPack.Text = String.Empty;
        Products.Text = String.Empty;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the code as follows by adding the created datatable to session state and then try to retrieve it whenever user click on the button.

```
protected void addInquiry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataTable dt=(DataTable)Session["Inquiry"];
  try
  {
         Quantity = QuantityTxt.Text;
         string Details = Request.Form[Products.UniqueID];
         SelectedProduct = Details.Split('!');
         ProductNo = SelectedProduct[0];
         ProductDescription = SelectedProduct[1];
         ProductSapPack = SelectedProduct[2];
         ProductID = SelectedProduct[3];
         if(dt==null)
         {
             dt= new DataTable();                       
         }             
         dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { 
                             new DataColumn("ProductID",typeof(int)),
                             new DataColumn("ProductNo", typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("SapPack",typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("Quantity",typeof(string)),
                             });

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr[0] = ProductID;
        dr[1] = ProductNo;
        dr[2] = ProductDescription;
        dr[3] = ProductSapPack;
        dr[4] = Quantity;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Inquiries.DataSource = dt;
        Inquiries.DataBind();
        Session.Add("Inquiry",dt);
  }
  finally
  {
        QuantityTxt.Text = String.Empty;
        Description.Text = String.Empty;
        SapPack.Text = String.Empty;
        Products.Text = String.Empty;
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked when i did this
    if(dt==null)
            {
                 dt= new DataTable();
                 dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { 
                                 new DataColumn("ProductID",typeof(int)),
                                 new DataColumn("ProductNo", typeof(string)),
                                 new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)),
                                 new DataColumn("SapPack",typeof(string)),
                                 new DataColumn("Quantity",typeof(string)),
                                 });      }

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are not saving data in the database, you do need to create a Session/ViewState to save your DataTable.

```
if(Session["Products"] != null)
 dt = (DataTable) Session["Products"]; 
else
 dt = new DataTable(); // For the first time creates a new DataTable otherwise reads from Session variable

----
At the end, save the data to the Session variable:
Session["Products"] = dt;
```